# How to add app_dev.php to asset in Symfony 2

Tags: url, symfony, assets

I am using:

```
{{ asset('contact') }} (e.g.)
```

to generate the URL for my contact page, which outputs:

```
http://localhost.project/contact.
```

But I am in development enviroment.

How can I make asset display url for development enviroment?

As it should be:

```
http://localhost.project/web/app_dev.php/contact
```

Not

```
http://localhost.project/web/contact
```

Comment: Call your page via the app_dev.php to get into dev env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Symfony 2.3 you can set the assets_base_url in your config.yml file. The way i handle this is to add a %domain% variable to my parameter.yml file and have one for production and one for development. This way the assets are loaded with the correct urls as you suggest.

Add the following to your config file under framework -> templating

```
//app/config/config.yml

framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_url: %domain%
```

Then in your parameters.yml:

```
//app/config/parameters.yml - Dev environment

parameters:
    domain: 'http://localhost.project/web/'
```

Then for your production environment you will need your parameters.yml to differ and have the domain you plan to use.

With this set when you use the twig asset function it will prepend the base url that you want.

```
{{ asset('contact') }}
```

Will become:

```
http://localhost.project/web/contact
```

That being said. Assets are things like images, css, javascripts, fonts, etc. If you are trying to create a url to a page in your application then you want to use the twig path function.

```
{{ path('route.name') }}
```

This uses symfony's route name that you define in your routing.yml to generate the url for the page you are requesting.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `{{ path('your_route') }}` to generate URLs. This will generate appropriate URL for dev environment.